# Ошибка при запуске nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: nginx, centos7

Сервер при обращении к сайтам выдаёт: "Не удается получить доступ к сайту". Предположил, что проблема с nginx.

```
[root@static ~]# sudo nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
[root@static ~]#
```

Как починить всё?

Answer (score 1):

`98: Address already in use` означает, что порт уже занят.

Посмотрите, кто использует порт с помощью `sudo netstat -pan | grep ":80"`. Там будет что-то типо такого:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5808/nginx: worker
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5808/nginx: worker
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      6883/node
```

И убейте потом процесс.

Comment: [root@static www]# sudo netstat -pan | grep ":80"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3628/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 148.251.67.79:44752     148.251.67.79:80        TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 148.251.67.79:44746     148.251.67.79:80        TIME_WAIT   -

Comment: @Stas ну, значит у вас уже запущен nginx.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. как узнать в чем проблема тогда?

Comment: @Stas думаю, это нужно отдельным вопрос задать. Скорей всего что-то в настройках сайта в самом nginx.

Comment: @Stas задайте новым вопросом и приложите настройки nginx для сайта.

Comment: если бы я знал как задать вопрос , возможно я бы нашел ответ. подскажите как сформулировать проблему? спасибо

Comment: настройки для сайта это какой файл? повторюсь у меня проблем с сайтом до сегодня не было. настройки не менял

Comment: @Stas к примеру, "Не получается открыть сайт. Вот настройки nginx. Вот логи php и nginx. Вот такая ошибка. Что делать?"

Comment: я сам в меру своих умственных способностей и минимального опыта администрирую свой сервер... с такой сложностью сталкиваюсь впервые

Comment: могу я здесь оставить логи? тему можно создавать с интервалом в 40 минут?